# Search on aggregated list of integers Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, aggregation

I'm designing a new Index and have some structures in my data that could possibly cause some trouble for searching.

Given a doc type 'catalog' (to transpose it to a more general setting)

with the following data structure,

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "categories": [
    {
      "category_name": "aaaa",
      "nb_items": 6
    },
    {
      "category_name": "bbbb",
      "nb_items": 5
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": 2,
  "categories": [
    {
      "category_name": "cccc",
      "nb_items": 9
    },
    {
      "category_name": "bbbb",
      "nb_items": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

How to query a document whose number of items accross all category (sum of nb_items by category_names) is > 10 but nb_items in category bbbb is > 4 to retrieve only the first document ?

Would it be easier with two independant lists categories and nb_items or with such nested documents ?

Comment: Please clarify: **How to query a document whose number of items accross all category (sum of nb_items by category_names) is > 10 but nb_items in category bbbb is > 4 to retrieve only the first document ?** using e.g.

Comment: doc 1 is selected because( 6+5 > 10 and 5 > 4) 

and doc 2 is not selected because (9+2 > 10 but 2 < 4)






My main issue here for my query is how to issue a condition on the sum of "nb_items" in the array

Answer (score 0):

This sould work. You could made the total nb condition with a script in the filter part but it would be really slow.

```
  {
      "size": 0,
      "query" : {
    "nested" : {
        "path" : "categories",
        "query" : {
            "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                    {
                        "term" : {"categories.origin" : "bbbb"}
                    },
                    {
                        "range" : {"categories.nb_items" : {"gt" : 4}}
                    }
                ]}
            }
        }
    },
      "aggregations": {
        "totalnbbydoc": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "youriddoc",
            "size": 10000
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "totalByNested": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "categories"
              },
              "aggregations": {
                "nbtotal": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "categories.nb_items"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "paidAmount_filter": {
              "bucket_selector": {
                "script": {
                  "inline": "params.totalnbbydoc > 10"
                },
                "buckets_path": {
                  "totalnbbydoc": "totalByNested>nbtotal"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```